# How can I sort related entities in Ebean?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am using Play Framework and Ebean ORM. Say, I have 2 related entity classes (Card.java and FinalMark.java)

Card.java

```
@Entity
public class Card extends Model {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  . . .
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "card")
  public List<FinalMark> finalMarks;
  . . .
  public static Finder<Integer, Card> find =
    new Finder<>(Integer.class, Card.class);

}
```

FinalMark.java

```
@Entity
public class FinalMark extends Model {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  public Card card;
  . . .
  public static Finder<Integer, FinalMark> find = new Finder<>(Integer.class,
    FinalMark.class);
}
```

When I fetching `Card` instance (by Card.find.byId() for example), All related `FinalMark` instances also will be fetched. But how can I sort them? Is it possible by Ebean or I should sort resulting list?

Thank you for wasting your time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add the `@javax.persistence.OrderBy` annotation on your `@OneToMany` field.

For example, if you have a `position` field on your `FinalMark` entity, you could order on that field with this code :

```
@Entity
public class Card extends Model {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "card")
    @OrderBy("position asc")
    public List<FinalMark> finalMarks;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this

`Card.find.byId().orderBy("id asc");` //this will give the sorted order by id (entity)