# find.all sort oneTomany in Ebean

Tags: playframework, ebean

I'm following [How can I sort related entities in Ebean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925538/how-can-i-sort-related-entities-in-ebean/32621345#32621345) but i got this error

```
 RuntimeException: Can not find Master [class models.Card] 
 in Child[models.FinalMark]
```

Is the solution forgot to put this? Even with ID stil not working.

```
@Id
public Integer id;
```

I think my case quite similar.

```
@Entity
public class Club extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy("name asc")
    public List<Male> male = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy("name asc")
    public List<Female> female = new ArrayList<>();

    private static Finder<Long, Club> find = 
    new Finder<>(Long.class, Club.class);
}

@Entity
public class Male extends Model {
  @Id
  public Long id;
  public String name;
  private static Finder<Long, Male> find = new Finder<>(Long.class, Male.class);
}

@Entity
public class Female extends Model {
  @Id
  public Long id;
  @ManyToOne
  public Club club;
  public String name;
  private static Finder<Long, Female> find = new Finder<>(Long.class, Female.class);
}
```

I've intial data

```
male:
- !!models.Male &m1
    name:           "Martin"

- !!models.Male &m2
    name:           "Alan"

female:
- !!models.Female &f1
    name:           "June"

- !!models.Female &f2
    name:           "Babe"


club:
- !!models.Club
    name:           "BigClub"
    male:
    - *m1
    - *m2
    female:
    - *f1
    - *f2
```

during initialization.

```
    Map<String, List<Object>> all = (Map<String, List<Object>>) Yaml
                    .load("initial-data.yml");

   // Insert club
   Ebean.save(all.get("club"));
```

when i call Club.find.all(), the male and female fields still not sort in ascending. I've tried 2 different ways (each in male & female). both also not sort in asc. any idea?

Comment: do you have any other models? since ebean is trying to find model card class which isn't there

Comment: What's Person.class?  Your finder in the Club class is referring to Person.class

Comment: @Seroney, It was referring to the solution in my first statement (please refer to the hyperlink)

Comment: @Atif, naming error and corrected. example here has changed the actual name for better illustration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the "path" of the related object when you are configuring the order-by like so:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderBy("male.name asc")
public List<Male> male = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderBy("female.name asc")
public List<Female> female = new ArrayList<>();
```

Otherwise, it thinks that you're referring to "name" field of the current class.

Comment: sorry, i should mentioned i'm using old ebean. After ported, the latest play-ebean in 2.4. it is working with "id asc". your suggestion is not working. Anyway, thanks.